# regular expression to validate accents, spaces and only letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that validates accents, and that also does not allow characters different from accents and allows spaces but not characters other than letters. I currently use this but I get an error for the spaces. How can I fix it?

```
function cambiarNombre(nombre){
 let regex = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+(\s*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*)*[a-zA-   
 ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]+$/g;
 return regex.exec(nombre)[0];
}
console.log(cambiarNombre("UNA palabra ñoÑerías ")); //true
console.log(cambiarNombre("UNA palabra ñoÑerías*")); //false *
console.log(cambiarNombre("UN2A palabra1 5oÑerías")); //false 2 1 5
console.log(cambiarNombre("palabra2")); //false 2
console.log(cambiarNombre(" palabra2")); //false 2
console.log(cambiarNombre(" pálabña ")); //true
console.log(cambiarNombre("juan perez")); //true
console.log(cambiarNombre("juan pérez")); //true
console.log(cambiarNombre("juan")); //true
console.log(cambiarNombre("júan")); //true
```

allow accents, spaces and letters.
Thank you

Comment: Give an example input and expected output.

Comment: Your regex only allow Spaces in the middle, is that on purpose?

Comment: @PoulBak I updated the question, basically I should allow spaces, accents, and letters.

Comment: Ok, Spaces at the end, in the middle, but not at the start, is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match letters, accents and Spaces everywhere, except Spaces at start, you can use the following regex (which is actually simpler than the one you have):

```
/^[ a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\u00f1\u00d1]*$/g
```

This will select all the different letters at start, the same + `Space` for the following.

Note the `space` in the pattern, if you want to match all `White Space`, you can use `\s` instead,

**Edit**:

Now Spaces are allowed at any position but NOT required. The only requirement is that all characters must be one of the characters in the Square brackets repeated zero or more times.

Comment: thanks! almost perfect! but you got it wrong spaces are not strictly necessary but are allowed in any position.

Comment: thanks for your help but it not works good.. for example "juan perez" should be true...

Comment: allow accents, spaces and letters,  but it does not necessarily mean that all are required.

Comment: 'juan perez' DOES match! Are you sure you have copied the regex correct? In particular you must use Square brackets, not ordinary ones. You must also include the Space.